# Magento 2 : theme

Tags: magento2, custom, header

How can we add custom text before welcome massage at panel wrapper?

**Note:** i don't want to display link, I just want to display plain text there.

Comment: please attach screen shot or custom text are static or dynamic ??

Comment: dynamic its a phone number and address

Comment: Can you add screenshot how it should look?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot, Its would be helpful for understand and answer you question..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159029)

Answer (score 0):

Content > Design > Configuration > Select your theme >

you see

> Header

text input fields

Comment: there is no Header in My theme